# How do I move vertices in geometry nodes

Tags: vertices, geometry-nodes

I’m wondering how to move vertices without vertex groups.

I’m kinda new to Geo Nodes. So please help!

Comment: What is your task? It is depends on that are  you trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move individual vertices with the `Set Position` node and use a condition (e.g. with index) to move a specific vertex as follows:

[image]

Comment: I can't find the "Equal" node. Btw, I'm using blender 3.2

Comment: search for "compare", than change to equal [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3461.png

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome